# Editing *row* names of tabular display when using stat_fit_tb() in ggpmisc & ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

While `stat_poly_eq()` allows variable names to be changed using `eq.with.lhs` and `eq.x.rhs`, a similar functionality does not seem to be available within `stat_fit_tb()`, according to my reading of the **ggpmisc** documentation.

Is there a way of modifying the `plt` object in the following example to force the table display to show parameter names that are easier on the eye and more consistent with the equation and axis labels?

```
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(month = c(1:60))
df$observed <- 2.5 + 0.05*df$month + rnorm(60, sd = 1)
```

```
## min plot example
my.formula <- y ~ poly(x,2,raw=TRUE) ## formula with generic variable names

plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=observed)) +
  geom_point() +
  ## show fit and CI
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, level=0.95, formula = my.formula) +
  ## display equation with useful variable names (i.e. not x and y)
  stat_poly_eq(eq.with.lhs = "italic(Obs)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = ".month",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE,
               formula = my.formula, label.y = 0.9) +
  ## show table of each coefficient's p-value
  stat_fit_tb(method.args = list(formula = my.formula),
              tb.vars = c(parameter = "term", ## can change column headings
                          coeff = "estimate", 
                          "p-val" = "p.value"),
              label.y = 0.8, label.x = "left")

plt
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: This is something I should add to the next version of 'ggpmisc'. Meanwhile in my answer below I show a hack to achieve this.

Comment: Now available in Bitbucket, will be released as 'ggpmisc' 0.3.7 in a few weeks time.

Comment: Now in CRAN. Got the update ready during the weekend. Please, see new answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.3.7) makes this answer possible, and in my view should be the preferred one.

```
## ggpmisc (>= 0.3.7)
library(ggpmisc)

## dummy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(month = c(1:60))
df$observed <- 2.5 + 0.05*df$month + rnorm(60, sd = 1)

## min plot example
my.formula <- y ~ poly(x,2,raw=TRUE) ## formula with generic variable names

plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=observed)) +
  geom_point() +
  ## show fit and CI
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, level=0.95, formula = my.formula) +
  ## display equation with useful variable names (i.e. not x and y)
  stat_poly_eq(eq.with.lhs = "italic(Obs)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = '" month"',
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE,
               formula = my.formula, label.y = 0.9) +
  ## show table of each coefficient's p-value
  stat_fit_tb(method.args = list(formula = my.formula),
              tb.vars = c(parameter = "term", ## can change column headings
                          coeff = "estimate",
                          "p-val" = "p.value"),
              tb.params = c(1, month = 2, "month^2" = 3), ##
              label.y = 0.8, label.x = "left",
              parse = TRUE)

plt
```

Giving the following plot. (I did also change the argument to `eq.x.rhs` although not directly part of the question. The nicer formatting of *P*-values is as implemented in the new version of the 'ggpmisc' package.)

[image: generated plot]

Comment: Thank you! I do like the rounding of the p-value for the summary table (....I know others will disagree). In your next release you may wish to suppress the multiple 'Dropping column(s)...' messages for facets. I had a tabulation error when I tried tb.vars = c(coeff = "estimate", "p-val" = "p.value"), i.e. to have a smaller table with just those columns, although there's a different error when tb.params = c(intercept = 1, ...).

Comment: @BigOldDave The "dropping columns..." are R messages, so they can be silenced by enclosing the code in suppressMessages() . In Rmarkdown chunks you can use message=FALSE to suppress them. In the next version I will implement its own option for this. I think that because the interface is a bit unusual it is better to warn users that columns are being dropped, but I may change my mind later on.

Comment: @BigOldDave The tabulation error happens when you remove the column that tb.params is expected to modify, as columns are deleted before renaming the parameters. Probably the easiest solution is to change the order of these two operations in the code for the next version... One never does enough testing...! Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: @BigOldDave Thanks again! I decided to fix the code instead of raising an issue to remind myself. The error you reported is now handled with a message. Dropping columns message is now issued only if the column dropped is the one with the parameter names, which I do not expect many users to want to delete. Messages are also triggered if rows are dropped, as this again seems not a wise thing to do. The rounding of p-values can now be disabled by the user and the number of digits also set. These changes are now pushed to Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be hacked after converting `plt` to a grob object, but nowadays I like to solve a problem once & be done with it, so I hacked the underlying ggproto object instead.

Run the following code (changes from the original are indicated in comments):

```
library(ggpmisc)

StatFitTb2 <- ggproto(
  "StatFitTb2",
  StatFitTb,
  compute_panel = function (data, scales, method, method.args, tb.type, tb.vars, 
                            tb.row.names, digits, npc.used = TRUE, label.x, label.y) {
    force(data)
    if (length(unique(data$x)) < 2) {
      return(data.frame())
    }
    panel.idx <- as.integer(as.character(data$PANEL[1]))
    if (length(label.x) >= panel.idx) {
      label.x <- label.x[panel.idx]
    }
    else if (length(label.x) > 0) {
      label.x <- label.x[1]
    }
    if (length(label.y) >= panel.idx) {
      label.y <- label.y[panel.idx]
    }
    else if (length(label.y) > 0) {
      label.y <- label.y[1]
    }
    method.args <- c(method.args, list(data = quote(data)))
    if (is.character(method)) 
      method <- match.fun(method)
    mf <- do.call(method, method.args)
    if (tolower(tb.type) %in% c("fit.anova", "anova")) {
      mf_tb <- broom::tidy(stats::anova(mf))
    }
    else if (tolower(tb.type) %in% c("fit.summary", "summary")) {
      mf_tb <- broom::tidy(mf)
    }
    else if (tolower(tb.type) %in% c("fit.coefs", "coefs")) {
      mf_tb <- broom::tidy(mf)[c("term", "estimate")]
    }
    num.cols <- sapply(mf_tb, is.numeric)
    mf_tb[num.cols] <- signif(mf_tb[num.cols], digits = digits)
    if (!is.null(tb.vars)) {
      mf_tb <- dplyr::select(mf_tb, !!tb.vars)
    }
    
    # new condition for modifying row names, if they are specified
    if(!is.null(tb.row.names)) {
      mf_tb[, 1] <- tb.row.names
    }
    
    z <- tibble::tibble(mf_tb = list(mf_tb))
    if (npc.used) {
      margin.npc <- 0.05
    }
    else {
      margin.npc <- 0
    }
    if (is.character(label.x)) {
      label.x <- switch(label.x, right = (1 - margin.npc), 
                        center = 0.5, centre = 0.5, 
                        middle = 0.5, left = (0 + margin.npc))
      if (!npc.used) {
        x.delta <- abs(diff(range(data$x)))
        x.min <- min(data$x)
        label.x <- label.x * x.delta + x.min
      }
    }
    if (is.character(label.y)) {
      label.y <- switch(label.y, top = (1 - margin.npc), center = 0.5, 
                        centre = 0.5, middle = 0.5, bottom = (0 + margin.npc))
      if (!npc.used) {
        y.delta <- abs(diff(range(data$y)))
        y.min <- min(data$y)
        label.y <- label.y * y.delta + y.min
      }
    }
    if (npc.used) {
      z$npcx <- label.x
      z$x <- NA_real_
      z$npcy <- label.y
      z$y <- NA_real_
    }
    else {
      z$x <- label.x
      z$npcx <- NA_real_
      z$y <- label.y
      z$npcy <- NA_real_
    }
    z
  })

stat_fit_tb2 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "table_npc",
                         method = "lm", method.args = list(formula = y ~ x), 
                         tb.type = "fit.summary", tb.vars = NULL, digits = 3, 
                         tb.row.names = NULL, # new parameter for row names (defaults to NULL)
                         label.x = "center", label.y = "top", label.x.npc = NULL, 
                         label.y.npc = NULL, position = "identity", table.theme = NULL, 
                         table.rownames = FALSE, table.colnames = TRUE, table.hjust = 1, 
                         parse = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE, inherit.aes = TRUE, 
                         ...) {
  if (!is.null(label.x.npc)) {
    stopifnot(grepl("_npc", geom))
    label.x <- label.x.npc
  }
  if (!is.null(label.y.npc)) {
    stopifnot(grepl("_npc", geom))
    label.y <- label.y.npc
  }
  ggplot2::layer(stat = StatFitTb2, # reference modified StatFitTb2 instead of the original
                 data = data, mapping = mapping, 
                 geom = geom, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, 
                 inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
                 params = list(method = method, method.args = method.args, 
                               tb.type = tb.type, tb.vars = tb.vars, 
                               tb.row.names = tb.row.names, # new parameter here
                               digits = digits, label.x = label.x, label.y = label.y, 
                               npc.used = grepl("_npc", geom), table.theme = table.theme, 
                               table.rownames = table.rownames, table.colnames = table.colnames, 
                               table.hjust = table.hjust, parse = parse, na.rm = na.rm, 
                               ...))
}
```

Usage:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=observed)) +
  geom_point() +
  ## show fit and CI
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, level=0.95, formula = my.formula) +
  ## display equation with useful variable names (i.e. not x and y)
  stat_poly_eq(eq.with.lhs = "italic(Obs)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = ".month",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE,
               formula = my.formula, label.y = 0.9) +
  ## show table of each coefficient's p-value
  stat_fit_tb2(method.args = list(formula = my.formula),
              tb.vars = c(parameter = "term", ## can change column headings
                          coeff = "estimate", 
                          "p-val" = "p.value"),
              tb.row.names = c("(Intercept)", "month", "month^2"),
              label.y = 0.8, label.x = "left", parse = TRUE)
```

Note: `parse = TRUE` makes the `month^2` row name look nicer, but it also affects all other values in the table (e.g. the p-value's dash becomes a minus sign, numbers are rounded to different number of digits, etc.)

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! I will add this code to the package. If you make a pull request in Bitbucket or just send me (privately to the maintainer address) your approval (ORCID and e-mail address if you wish) I will add you as contributor.

Comment: @PedroAphalo Glad you find this useful :) Please go head to use the code. I think it's covered under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) like all new answers on SO these days.

Answer (score 2):

***NOTE:* If you are still using 'ggpmisc' (<= 0.3.6), this answer may be useful. Otherwise, see separate answer using 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.3.7).**

Until this is built into the package, a rather simple hack is to edit the tibble on the fly within `aes()`. I define a function first so as not to clutter the code.

```
library(ggpmisc)

## dummy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(month = c(1:60))
df$observed <- 2.5 + 0.05*df$month + rnorm(60, sd = 1)

## min plot example
my.formula <- y ~ poly(x,2,raw=TRUE) ## formula with generic variable names

## define function for renaming parameters in tibble(s) returned by the stat
## walk through the list an operate on all the tibbles found so that
## grouping and facets are also supported.
set_param_names <- function(x, names) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
   x[[i]][[1]] <- names
  }
  x
}

plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=observed)) +
  geom_point() +
  ## show fit and CI
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, level=0.95, formula = my.formula) +
  ## display equation with useful variable names (i.e. not x and y)
  stat_poly_eq(eq.with.lhs = "italic(Obs)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = ".month",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE,
               formula = my.formula, label.y = 0.9) +
  ## show table of each coefficient's p-value
  stat_fit_tb(method.args = list(formula = my.formula),
              tb.vars = c(parameter = "term", ## can change column headings
                          coeff = "estimate", 
                          "p-val" = "p.value"),
              label.y = 0.8, label.x = "left",
              aes(label = set_param_names(stat(mf_tb), 
                                          c("intercept", "month", "month^2"))),
              parse = TRUE)

plt
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: The tibble is nested in a list. Even though I am the author, I used `geom_debug()` from package 'gginnards' to quickly check the names and structure of the data returned by the `stat_fit_tb()` statistic. This debug geometry can be used with any ggplot statistic.

Comment: Pedro - for facets, the initial function would need to name each tibble in the list. As it stands, the table ends up duplicated on each graph.

Comment: @BigOldDave Thanks for pointing this out! I edited the definition of `set_param_names()` in the answer so that it works correctly with facets.